# Change Wordpress logout url after changing wp-login.php to custom url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have changed the default login url for Wordpress by adding this to my themes functions.php

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'custom_login_url', PHP_INT_MAX );

function custom_login_url( $login_url ) {
$login_url = site_url( 'custom-access.php', 'login' );
    return $login_url;
}
```

I have then created a copy of wp-login.php in the root directory called custom-access.php and replaced all **wp-login** with **custom-access**

The new login url is working as expected and I have removed wp-login.php

The problem is that the logout url contains **wp-login.php?action=logout** etc which is no longer a valid url.

wp_logout_url() doesn't appear to have an option to change this, only to set where to redirect the user after logout. I could edit wp_logout_url() in wp-includes/general-template.php but that seems like a terrible idea.

1. How do i resolve this url to be **custom-access.php.php?action=logout**
2. But rather how do I logout the user without showing them the custom login in the url?

Comment: There is, surprise surprise, also a `logout_url` filter, which gets executed at the end of `wp_logout_url`. https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L408

Comment: Thanks - I'd missed this, but this still exposes the new login url to the user?

Comment: But that was "exposed" to them when they logged in already, no?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific - currently login is only possible through an Elementor form inside a settings widget - I want to effectively remove the option for anyone to login via the standard WP login page.

Comment: Not sure how exactly WP processes this, whether the logout "page" is actually necessary - or whether you could also just specify your base URL, `/`, as long as that URL parameter `?action=logout` is set ... but that's what I'd try first.

Comment: unfortunately it seems that ?action=logout must be set on the new login page url

Answer (score 3):

Not a perfect solution as the new login url can still be seen in the logout link, but this ensures:

1. wp_logout_url() does actually log a user out now that wp-login.php
   no longer exists
2. a user gets redirected to home instead of the new login page

Change the url for login to point to your

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_custom_login_url', PHP_INT_MAX );
function my_custom_login_url( $login_url ) {
    $login_url = site_url( 'custom-access.php', 'login' );
    return $login_url;
}
```

Also change the logout url once wp-login.php no longer exists

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'my_custom_logout_url', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_logout_url( $logout_url, $redirect ) {
    $logout_url = home_url( '/custom-access.php?action=logout' );
    $logout_url = wp_nonce_url( $logout_url, 'log-out' );
    return $logout_url;
}
```

Ensure logout doesnt take user to the new wp login page

```
add_action( 'wp_logout','my_custom_redirect_after_logout' );
function my_custom_redirect_after_logout() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was literally looking for this answer for a couple hours and no other stackoverflow article solved my problem until now. Thanks for posting!

Comment: @LokoWebDesign I still haven't managed to stop /wp-login.php from redirecting to the new custom login page (i'd like to keep this url hidden) - if you find a solution please post it!